# Простой парсер txt файла с помощью php

Tags: php, файлы

Друзья! Суть вопроса такова: каждые 2 минуты, на сервер прилетает txt-файл в каталог files. Моя задача обработать данные из этого файла. С файлами, к сожалению, я дела еще не имел, поэтому не знаю как грамотно с ними работать, но сроки выполнения данного задания очень поджимают, поэтому нужно начинать его обрабатывать чем скорее, тем лучше. А главное — правильно.

Вот что внутри файла:

```
1;i;iazs-v1.1.82
2;P;1;151587;202741;294725;0;0
3;R;1;0;6588;2503;0;7436;1862;0;0
4;R;2;0;5769;2065;-6;7533;1556;0;0
5;R;3;0;15586;7730;-2;8397;6491;0;0
6;T;1;18.04.2016 09:14:08;9;000000000000;255;777;18859;1;1;0;000000000000
7;T;2;18.04.2016 09:14:08;1;00000073487F;255;777;0;1;1;1;000000000000
8;T;3;18.04.2016 09:14:26;9;000000000000;255;777;26000;1;2;0;000000000000
9;T;4;18.04.2016 09:14:26;1;00000073487F;255;777;0;1;2;1;000000000000
10;#
```

Прилетающие файлы всегда одинаковы, то есть и по регламенту создания, и по  количеству параметров.

Вот что он обозначает:
Первая цифра строки - это чисто номер строки. Следующий после ";" это тип данных. 
Они бывают: P, R, T. Тип данных i обрабатывать не надо, это версия прошивки. Каждый из этих типов данных в строке имеет параметры которые разделены, а их количество всегда одно и то же.

Я, к сожалению, не знаю как реализовать такой парсер, но представляю это так: 
1) Открываем файл,
2) Заводим данные в цикл, завершающийся по окончанию файла.
3) Берем строку, берем второй элемент - тип данных, а дальше делаем, например, `switch`, с набором функций в зависимости от типа данных. Дальше я уже в этих функциях буду работать с массивом и обрабатывать данные.

Весь вопрос сводится по сути к этой структурировке:))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Как на счет использования функции [str-getcsv](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-getcsv.php) или [fgetcsv](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.fgetcsv.php)?

Пример использования:

```
<?php
  $row = 1;
  if (($handle = fopen("test.csv", "r")) !== FALSE) {
  while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ";")) !== FALSE) {
    $num = count($data);
    echo "<p> $num fields in line $row: <br /></p>\n";
    $row++;
    for ($c=0; $c < $num; $c++) {
        echo $data[$c] . "<br />\n";
    }
}
fclose($handle);
}
?>
```

> Это подойдет для txt?

Главное не расширение файла, а содержимое. Тут явно видно что это [CSV](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/CSV) файл с разделителем `;`

> и что значит while- 1000???

Выше приведены ссылки на функции которые могут Вам подойти. Если перейти по ссылкам то можно посмотреть на описание параметров и увидеть что 1000 это длина строки. Он стал необязательным в PHP 5. Если этот аргумент не указан (или равен 0 в версиях PHP 5.0.4 и выше), максимальная длинна строки не ограничена, при этом функция работает немного медленнее.

> мне нужно самое главное это вызвать функции обработки данных в зависимости от того какой тип

Ну так вместо `for ($c=0; $c < $num; $c++)` обратитесь к определенному элементу массива для вычитки типа и вызовите функцию с передачей остальных данных. Либо пишите свою реализацию построчной вычитки и обработки.

Comment: Это подойдет для txt? я к сожалению формат файла изменить не могу, это присылает txt файл оборудование

Comment: и что значит while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ";")) - 1000??? типа 1000 строк? но я навел в приер лишь фрагмент файла. он может быть и на 1000 строк и на больше

Comment: Простите но это не совсем удобно. мне нужно самое главное это вызвать функции обработки данных в зависимости от того какой тип данных в данный момент мы парсим. поэтому мне нужно четко уловить  какой это тип данных, вызвать функцию в зависимости от этого типа данных и передать в нее все параметры этой строки для обработки

Comment: @iSeeDev дополнил описание.

Comment: Cпасибо я уже реализовал то что хотел! Ваше решение мне помогло. спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

`$file = file_get_contents("Путь к файлу");`

Далее выдергиваем все что нужно через регулярки.

Например:

`preg_match("#\d+;[^i];(.*)", $file, $q);`

Answer (score 1):

```
$lines = file('имя_файла');  // Получаем все содержимое файла в массив

foreach ($lines as $line_num => $line) {
  $data=explode(';', $line);  // Разбиваем строку на массив колонок
  if($data[1]=='i') continue; // Не обрабатывать строки 'i'
  ...
}
```